HRESULT E_FAIL from COM Component When Scanning with WIA Visual Studio 2022
I am encountering a HRESULT E_FAIL error when attempting to scan images using the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) library in a C# application. Here’s the relevant portion of my code where the error occurs:
ImageFile img = (ImageFile)item.Transfer(SeraJPG ? wiaFormatJPEG : wiaFormatBMP);

Error Message:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

StackTrace:
   en WIA.IItem.Transfer(String FormatID)
   en WiaEasyImage.MainForm.AdquiereImagenDeScanner(String TipoDocumento, String ElIdentificadorDeDocumento, MensajeNoModal Progreso, String FicheroComprimido, Int32 NumeroHoja) en T:\Escaneador_version_ultima\MainForm.cs: línea 2393

Checked COM Registration: I have ensured that the WIA components are properly registered on the system.
Platform Compatibility: Verified that my project is targeting the correct platform (x86 or x64) and matches the COM component’s platform.
Service Status: Confirmed that the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service is running.
Error Handling: Wrapped the transfer code in a try-catch block to capture exceptions.
bool AcquireImageFromScanner(string DocumentType, string DocumentIdentifier, NonModalMessage Progress, string CompressedFile, int PageNumber)
{
    try
    {
        WIA.DeviceManager myManager = new WIA.DeviceManager();
        WIA.Device myScanner = OpenScannerSelector(myManager);

        if (myScanner == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No scanner currently connected.");
            return false;
        }

        // Configuring scanner
        ConfigureScanning(myScanner);

        foreach (WIA.Item item in myScanner.Items)
        {
            try
            {
                string wiaFormatBMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
                string wiaFormatJPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";

                ImageFile img = (ImageFile)item.Transfer(SeraJPG ? wiaFormatJPEG : wiaFormatBMP);
                // Process the scanned image
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error scanning image (COMException): {ex.Message} (HRESULT: {ex.ErrorCode})");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error acquiring image: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

